# How to add CountDown to this application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application that maximizes a window every so often, I want to add to this window a textblock that counts down to zero based on the number of seconds that a Quartz.net job would run

```
<Window x:Class="EyeCare2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Background="Orange"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" Closing="Window_Closing" >
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init();
        }


        private void Init()
        {
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();

            IDictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            map.Add("window", this);

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ShowJob>()
             .WithIdentity("showJob", "group")
             .UsingJobData(new JobDataMap(map))
             .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity("showTrigger", "group")
              .StartNow()
              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(20).RepeatForever())
              .Build();

            sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            sched.Start();
          //  sched.StartDelayed(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            //sched.StartDelayed(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Pause)
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do some stuff here 

            //Hide Window
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate(object o)
            {
                Hide();
                return null;
            }, null);

            //Do not close application
            e.Cancel = true; 
        }
    }

   public class ShowJob : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Window win = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("window") as Window;

            if (win != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    win.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight;
                    win.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight;
                    win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                    win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                    win.Topmost = true;
                    win.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    win.Show();
                }));

                IDictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                map.Add("window", win);

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HideJob>()
                 .WithIdentity("hideJob", "group")
                 .UsingJobData(new JobDataMap(map))
                 .Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                  .WithIdentity("hideTrigger", "group")
                  .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(40, IntervalUnit.Second))
                  .Build();

                context.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
        }
    }
public class HideJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Window win = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("window") as Window;
        if (win != null && Application.Current != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                win.Hide();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that maybe I could add a textblock and then use the dispatch timer to achieve this but not sure how to hook it up, I thought it might have to go somewhere int he ShowJob class but the distpatch timer is not running so I guessing it is something with it not being on the right thread.

Comment: Why isn't this in a view model, updating a bound property?

Comment: probably because the goal was to get it working as quick as possible with the least amount of time.

Comment: Well, a dispatcher timer could directly modify the textblock's text property. Its kind of hard to tell whats going on from the code. Can you do the simplest use case and just create a timer, verify it starts with a breakpoint, and have the elapsed set the Text property correctly?